# Use of STACK_OF(X509)

Tags: c++, x509certificate, x509, chain

I have a certificate chain in `STACK_OF(X509)` that I would like to verify. But I cannot seem to find how. How can I take individual certs out of this structure and verify them. Or verify the whole structure as a whole?

I am using  `SSL_get_peer_cert_chain(ssl)` to get the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [`openssl  verify`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/verify.html) utility to verify certificate chains.

You can look at the source in the git repository at [apps/verify.c](http://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blob;f=apps/verify.c;h=893670ff41321317e7a057e0a8c3fd64cb7d048a;hb=46ebd9e3bb623d3c15ef2203038956f3f7213620)